# NetworkImageView loading image from cache manually

Tags: android, android-volley, networkimageview

I am using a NetworkImageView inside a RecyclerView.Adapter to download some images and show them in a list.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Post current = mDataSet.get(position);

    NetworkImageView imgView = (NetworkImageView)holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
    imgView.setImageUrl(current.getImagePath(), ControllerVolley.getInstance().getImageLoader());
}
```

But I realize that everytime it tries to download the image again even if the image is already cached on disk.

The problem occurs when this download fails because since I can't set a Response.Listener into this NetworkImageView can't try to download it again.

So, I'm checking if the image is already cached to load it manually. I am using the CustomNetworkImageView recommended on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270152/volleys-networkimageview-setimagebitmap-method-doesnt-work) question.

```
  CustomNetworkImageView imgView = (CustomNetworkImageView)holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
  Cache.Entry entry = ControllerVolley.getInstance().getDiskCache().get("0:"+current.getImagePath());
    if (entry != null) {
        byte[] dataBitmap = entry.data;
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        imgView.setLocalImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dataBitmap, 0, dataBitmap.length, options));

    } else {
        imgView.setImageUrl(current.getImagePath(), ControllerVolley.getInstance().getImageLoader());

    }
```

But it does not load the bitmap .

Is there a better way to handle this situation?